# debian kernel upgrade to 2.6.32-5-amd64 but uname still shows 686

Tags: debian, kernel, 64-bit, upgrade

I'm try to upgrade a debian system to 2.6 64 bit kernel with the command

aptitude install linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64

which works fine.

The system reboots,
/vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64

all good

however uname -a returns

Linux hostname 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:01:19 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux

Am I missing something or is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else suffers this problem, 
I just needed to force grub to reconfigure (I had assumed that happened as part of the new kernel install).
So

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Then the new 64 bit kernel appeared and I could boot from it.
After that, a query of uname -a did indeed return x86_64

Answer (score 1):

One does not simply install a 64-bit kernel to change a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit installation. You usually have to completely reinstall the system.

That said, the Debian Wiki has a workaround which can be used to [migrate 32 to 64-bit on a live system](http://wiki.debian.org/Migrate32To64Bit), but it looks hairy enough that I'd probably just reinstall.

Comment: I was looking at [this](http://users.digitalkingdom.org/~rlpowell/hobbies/debian_arch_up/index.html), which seemed to suggest that the upgrade of the kernel would lead to uname giving a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Had to install the linux-headers too before running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64
```

then

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and finally reboot the system.

Thanks Mark from the previous answer... Can't up vote right now... don't have enough point :)